# how to insert json file to postgresql database using python?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, insert

**python code:**
as you can see i write the code there is something wrong in my code please help me

```
import requests
import json
import psycopg2
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 

con = psycopg2.connect(database='test', user='postgres', password='affan@123', host='localhost', port='5432')
cursor = con.cursor()
url = 'https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes'
page=urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'chrome'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
json_obj = str(response, 'utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

cursor.execute(
"""create table if not exists memes_data(
                id text, name text, url text, width integer, height integer, box_count integer);"""
)


for obj in json_obj:
    print(obj["id"])
    print(obj["name"])
    print(obj["url"])
    print(obj["width"])
    print(obj["height"])
    print(obj["box_count"])
   

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO memes_data (id, name, url, width, height, box_count) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (obj["id"], obj["name"], obj["url"], obj["width"], obj["height"], obj["box_count"]))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

**error while running**
there is the error you see that string indices must be integer so what can i do ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\shaik\Desktop\api ex\ob.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(obj["id"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Note that when you iterate over a dictionary, you're iterating over the keys. If you're just trying to print and use the values, you can do this instead: `for v in json_obj.values():`.

Answer (score 0):

some lines in your code are unnecessary. For example, you are declaring json_obj twice. Only the second gives you a dictionary. Also, you import requests but don't use it.

The part where you get your JSON object/dictionary can be reduced to:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes'
page = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'chrome'})
response = urlopen(page).read()
json_obj = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

Now you want to iter the memes in your json_obj. You need to declare the exact path of the list you want to iterate over:

```
memes = json_obj["data"]["memes"]
for obj in memes:
    print(obj["id"])
    print(obj["name"])
    print(obj["url"])
    print(obj["width"])
    print(obj["height"])
    print(obj["box_count"])
```